# Download of brotli compressed file: Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, xmlhttprequest, compression, brotli

Imagine this simple snippet that fetches a file:

```
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.onprogress = event => {
    console.log(`Progress: ${event.loaded}/${event.total}`)
  }    
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://example.com/myfile.data.br')
  xhr.send()
```

The file is brotli compressed, and served with the following response headers:

- `content-encoding: br`
- `content-length: 13934674`

According to the network tab, 13.94 MB gets transfered when fetching this file, and the resource size is 30.30 MB.

This is what Firefox' console looks like:

[image: Firefox console]

As you can see, it's respects the content-length, and is actually able to report progress on it.

This is what Chrome's console looks like:

[image]

Notice how both the `event.loaded` and `event.total` is different. Chrome seems to report progress on the actually resource size (not the compressed size!), but it doesn't know the total resource size (which makes sense because it's compressed so it doesn't know what the total resource size will be).

When digging a bit deeper, I actually noticed Chrome is just wrong here. It tells you it downloaded 30.30 MB, but it didn't, it only transferred 13.94 MB.

Even when you fetch this file directly via the browser, it looks like Chrome is fooling you (throttled my network to be able to capture it):

[image]

See how it's pretending to be downloading 30.30 MB (it's currently at 21.2 MB), while it's actually only downloading 13.94 MB. My download speed is then calculated based on that uncompressed resource size and the elapsed time, and therefor completely wrong. The blue progress bar is actually not a left-to-right progress bar but rather an animated "I don't know the total" progress bar, I just took my screenshot on this particular moment where it appears to be loaded from left to right, but it's not.

Firefox seems to do it better:

[image]

Here, we do have a total, and thus a left-to-right progress bar, and the correct download speed.

My questions:

- Is this behavior in Chrome expected?
- How to properly implement a progress bar that will work for both?